# (foreign keys) Dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to shrink a database by getting rid of data from it and one of the annoying things to do is run the delete query I want to, to find what dependency I need to remove next.

Does INFORMATION.SCHEMA contain anything that will come in handy? for this type of thing? If not can someone please advise a simple way of finding out what ones they are as 8 minutes waiting time is too long.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the table in management studio you can select 'View Dependencies'
This will show you all the tables, views and other objects that depend on this table and also the tables this table depends on

Comment: what error are you getting when you run your delete?

Comment: I resolved the problem  (it'll allow me to accept my own answer in 2 days. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Code used to resolve this (pay attention to 'PK_Table

```
SELECT
K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
order by 3
```